# Yii2 how to translate cascade select in where clause to activequery?

Tags: mysql, sql, yii2

Two tables `question`, `answer`, I need to dump all the unanswered questions for specific user. In sql

```
select * from question where question.user_id = user_id
and (select count(*) from answer where answer.question_id = question.id) = 0
```

But how could I turn this command to activequery?

```
Question::find()->where(['user_id' => user_id]) ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An active query to find each question for a given user with no answer.

```
Question::find()->leftJoin('answer', 'answer.question_id=question.id')
                ->where(['question.user_id' => $user_id])
                ->andWhere(['answer.id' => null)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query could be write this way

```
  select * from question 
  inner join answer on answer.question_id = question.id
  where question.user_id = user_id
  group by question.id 
  having count(*) > 0
```

and in activeRecored  you could use

```
 Question::find()->innerJoin('answer', answer.question_id = question.id)->
        where(['user_id' => user_id])->
        groupBy('id')->
        having('having count(*) > 0')->
```